# How do I add a predictive text to my search field for searching data from mysql data base?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

How do I add a predictive text to my search field for searching data from mysql data base? I have a data base with alot of information and i want to search specific names and phrases but instead of guess the word or text i wanted the search field to hint the word or phrase for me so i can select it.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: This feature is called "Auto-complete" ... there are many tutorials online on how to make them. Here is a video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfETuMdqZus

Comment: I don't recommended using MySQL for this. Use redis, mongo, couchdb, etc as a backend. A single collection of one indexed key. All of the above have regex matching available.